# how to pass a dynamic div id to highchart

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, highcharts

I have dynamic tab created using Jquery Ui. I want to add a high chart to the div created by the Jquery ui. When i pass this id to "renderTo"  of Highchart options  it says error #13.
I have looked up for it and according to it Highcharts couldn't find the Div.

So any suggestion how i can fix this..?

```
function miniG_help()
{

    $("#tab_container").tabs("add","#tabs-1","123");
         $( "#tab_container" ).tabs( "refresh" );
    plotGraph(url_temp,"#tabs-1");  
}

function plotGraph(url,divId)
{
..................
options.chart={renderTo: divId};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the div hasn't been written to the dom yet, and does not exist when you try to create the chart.  Make sure your element is written to the page before creating the chart.

One suggestion would be to call the method to create the chart on load of the tabs.  There is a "load" event you can tie this to (http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load):

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
    load: function( event, ui ) {
        //call method to create chart now
    }
});
```

Comment: $( "#tab_container" ).tabs({
load:function(event,ui){
alert("Eureka!!");
}
});  

i have added this but  this particular alert "Eureka!" never showed up

Comment: you probably have another error.  Are your tabs actually being created? Do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined // for jquery 1.7.2
 but i dont know if it has any effect.

Comment: I am pretty certain it does. You will have to fix this first